# Dynamic Navigation Rules

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

On a Custom Control I have defined a Navigation Rule xsp-success go to xpDemo.xsp. This works fine, but the Navigation rule is probably one of the only places that there is not the little blue diamond to allow for a computed result. What I want to do is something like this

(viewScope.get("vsSomething") == "Something) ? "/xpSomeWhere.xsp" : "/xpSomeWhereElse.xsp"

I could define a different xsp-??? for each possible success but that would be a blow-up waiting to happen. 
In addition I want to re-use the CC in several different situations and the major difference is that where I want to navigate to. I could do a context.reDirectTo() but that then means that I have to repeat the code many times in several different places that might not be totally obvious thus creating a maintenance headache. The obvious place would seem to be the Navigation Rules. I can't believe that I'm the first person wanting to do this but my search has turned up nothing.

Comment: Bill, if you're not blogging, this looks like an issue that would be a good piece of code for a first blog entry. An interesting, undocumented solution to a problem that I'm sure others are having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can indeed be computed, just not using the "Navigation" section of the properties pane. If you go instead to the XSP source or to the "navigationRules" element of the "All Properties" section, you can modify the "viewId" property to include a computed value as normal.

Comment: Thanks Jesse - so if I'm trying to set a rule for xsp-success then that would be the value I would enter in the outcome field?

Comment: Yep. If you first add the rule via the other parts of the properties pane, it'll create the entry in the All Properties view for you to modify as well.

Comment: Messing around with it to get it to do what I want, but that is going to be the fix. Not exactly obvious, but then....